# Paperclip Geometry class no longer works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geometry, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm using Rails with the Paperclip gem for image uploads. I don't know when it happened because I just noticed now, but at some point in the recent past they must have changed the Geometry class, because it's now throwing an error.  I'm using Paperclip 3.3.1

I used to use:

```
Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(photo.path(style))
```

to get the photo geometry, but now when I do that I get:

```
undefined method `to_file' for #<Paperclip::Attachment:0x007feba0009fb8>
```

I've been snooping around in the source for some leads, but this is not my forté, and I'm not finding anything too revealing.

Anybody

Answer (score 2):

I'm using 3.3.1, and have this in my photo.rb to update my photo record before saving.

```
  def do_before_save
    temp = self.image.queued_for_write[:original]
    unless temp.nil?
      geo = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(temp)
      self.image_width = geo.width
      self.image_height = geo.height
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for S3 with privacy settings as it's downloading file to /tmp folder

```
Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(Paperclip.io_adapters.for(photo).path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. If anyone else used the cropping code from the Railscast on Paperclip, all I had to did to fix it was to change photo.path to photo.url. I'm using S3, and for some reason the relative path used to work, but it now requires the full URL.